# add field in wordpress user-new.php through php

Tags: php, wordpress

On the Users.php page I need an automatic filter to list only one type of user, without having to select an accurate filter that opens the page and is already with this filter

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding your question. Could you provide more information? Do you have any code yet that we could look at? I'm not familiar with users.php in a WordPress theme

Comment: I need to automatically add a value to a WP_USERS table.

Comment: As Stevish, I also believe your question isn't clear enough to understand what is it you're trying to do. Please elaborate a bit more so we can help you out.

Comment: I need to automatically add a value to new columm a WP_USERS table

Comment: I think that you will want to utilize user metadata for that. Directly accessing (and especially changing) a WordPress database is a very bad practice. Check out https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/working-with-user-metadata/ for how to work with usermeta. Then if you want to modify the users screen in the admin area, look for actions and filters that will give you access to that table: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/

Comment: i need direct PHP

Answer (score 4):

Try this inside your functions file:

Create a custom field, "Company Name". It is shown on both Add/Update user screens.
Hook “user_new_form”, will display the field on Add New User screen.

```
function custom_user_profile_fields($user){
    if(is_object($user))
        $company = esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'company', $user->ID ) );
    else
        $company = null;
    ?>
    <h3>Extra profile information</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="company">Company Name</label></th>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="regular-text" name="company" value="<?php echo $company; ?>" id="company" /><br />
                <span class="description">Where are you?</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'custom_user_profile_fields' );
add_action( "user_new_form", "custom_user_profile_fields" );
```

Save the custom field in database:

```
function save_custom_user_profile_fields($user_id){
    # again do this only if you can
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options'))
        return false;

    # save my custom field
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'company', $_POST['company']);
}
add_action('user_register', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields');
add_action('profile_update', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields');
```

Comment: @Lucas Augusto You add all code in functions.php and on page `/wp-admin/user-new.php` did not show [that](https://ibb.co/gRTTrDN)?

Comment: on the page appears, but does not save the value in the database

Comment: What happens when you save new user or update with filled new field? Maybe some error? And you do this from admin user?
What your WP and PHP version? I test this code on WordPress 5.0.4 and PHP Version 7.1.18

Comment: it saves all normal fields from the table, no error appears

Comment: version more recent to WP

Comment: @LucasAugusto Try to change the second function like this:
`function save_custom_user_profile_fields($user_id){
    # save my custom field
    update_user_meta($user_id, 'company', $_POST['company']);
}
add_action('user_register', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields');
add_action('profile_update', 'save_custom_user_profile_fields');`